# Playing incoming MIDI note on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, midi

I have figured out how to catch incoming MIDI over Bluetooth messages from apps that can already do this (actually sending them myself is a lesson for another day). However I have no idea how I would play these notes in my application.

I looked at AVMIDIPlayer but I only figured out how to play an already existing MIDI-file with that, is there a way to play a sound with a certain note and velocity that I received from the other app?